# Class Wide Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I'm trying to create a class wide array in C#, in a Windows Mobile Phone 8.1 project, so that when I create a method I can

What I did at first was:

```
    public sealed partial class GamePage : Page
    {
        int Score = 0;
        int count = 0;
        private DispatcherTimer Timer;
        public ColorsClass color = new ColorsClass();
        public int RandBlue = 0;
        int RandGreen = 0;
        int RandRed = 0;
        int RandYellow = 0;
        int RandPurple = 0;
        int RandYellowGreen = 0;
        int RandOrange = 0;
        int RandGray = 0;
        bool Equal = true;
        int Fail;
        int Hit;
        int Lives = 10;
            Rectangle[] Block = { Block01, Block02, Block03, Block04, Block05, Block06, Block07, Block08, Block09, Block10, Block11, Block12 };
           int[] RandomColors = { RandBlue, RandGreen, RandRed, RandYellow, RandPurple, RandYellowGreen, RandGray };

...

}
```

But it gives me the message that "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property..."

Then I tried this option, that I saw when I was search in the internet:

```
    public sealed partial class GamePage : Page
    {
        int Score = 0;
        int count = 0;
        private DispatcherTimer Timer;
        public ColorsClass color = new ColorsClass();
        public int RandBlue = 0;
        int RandGreen = 0;
        int RandRed = 0;
        int RandYellow = 0;
        int RandPurple = 0;
        int RandYellowGreen = 0;
        int RandOrange = 0;
        int RandGray = 0;
        bool Equal = true;
        int Fail;
        int Hit;
        int Lives = 10;
        int [] 
        Random rand = new Random();

        public GamePage()
        {

            this.InitializeComponent();

        DispatchTheTime();
        RandomColors = new int[] { RandBlue, RandGreen, RandRed, RandYellow, RandPurple, RandYellowGreen, RandGray };
...

}
```

This way I can reach the array through the methods I created, but the array values are always null..

What can I do?

Comment: *but the array values are always null.* ? Are you sure? Where you're trying to access it? Inside the `DispatchTheTime` method?

Comment: Which Array? Your second example you start the declaration of an int array but don't finish it. FYI, variables declared outside of functions have class wide scope, meaning they can be accessed across your entire class. If you mean program wide you need a static array with public access.

Comment: change this line 'Rectangle[] Block = { Block01, Block02, Block03, Block04, Block05, Block06, Block07, Block08, Block09, Block10, Block11, Block12 };' to 'Rectangle[] Block = new Rectangle { Block01, Block02, Block03, Block04, Block05, Block06, Block07, Block08, Block09, Block10, Block11, Block12 };' and try again

Comment: He propably means 0 (zero) not null

Comment: I wanted to say that the array itself is null... sorry, for all the trouble, but I'm starting in programming... I've been battling with this for the last 2 days.. My program is all ready, but I have to initiate the arrays in every methods that I want to use them... So I thought that there must be a way to not doing so..

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that integers are valuetypes. If you create an array of integers like with the RandomColors, you'll just put a copy of your value in the array. At this point, RandGreen and RandomColors[1] point to different memory locations and a change of either won't propagate to the other.
You have to decide whether you want to keep your values in a lot of fields like you actually declared or if you want to keep your integers in an array.

You are propably better off using a Dictionary for your usecase and only access the integers from there.

On class level declare your RandomColors:

```
Dictionary<string, int> RandomColors = new Dictionary<string, int>();



public GamePage()
{
    RandomColors.Add("RandGreen", 0);
    RandomColors.Add("RandRed", 0);


    //change like this:
    RandomColors["RandGreen"] = 5;

    //access like this:
    int x = RandomColors["RandGreen"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime when you create a new `GamePage` you are filling your array with the content of the variables `RandGreen`, `RandRed`, ...

At this time, these variables are set to `0`. Thus your array contains only `0`s. Even if you later assign other values to `RandGreen`, `RandRed`, ... the values within the array will not change.

I hope this example will make it clearer:

```
RandBlue = 0;
var RandomColors = new int[] { RandBlue, RandGreen }; 
// RandColors[0] is 0
RandBlue = 5;
// RandColors[0] is still 0
```

---

**Edit:**

The error message "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property..." should be self-explaining. You could make your color variables `const` in order to make it work. But I suppose this would not make any sense for you.